Layout not moving up with keyboard when BottomNavigationView is GONE
In my activity I have the FragmentContainerView & a BottomNavigationView. Whenever the BottomNavigationView visibility is set to VISIBLE, the layout works as intended (goes up with the keyboard), but when I set it to GONE, the FragmentContainerView remains behind the keyboard and doesn't move up with it. I have set adjustResize|adjustPan in my manifest but it still behaves this way.
Button from FragmentContainerView hidden behind keyboard when BottomNavigationView is GONE
Layout working correctly but only when BottomNavigationView is VISIBLE
Activity.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
        style="@style/BottomNavigationViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/ActiveIndicatorStyle"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Fragment.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ui.add_transaction.AddTransactionFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
                android:text="@string/add_transaction"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/type_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/titleTextView">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/income" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/expense" />
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/amountTextField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/type_tab_layout"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_from_border"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_from_border"
                android:hint="@string/amount"
                app:prefixText="$">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/categories_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/amountTextField"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_from_border"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_from_border">

                <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                    android:id="@+id/chipGroupCategories"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:singleLine="true"
                    app:singleSelection="true" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/accounts_scroll_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/categories_scroll_view"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_from_border"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_from_border">

                <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                    android:id="@+id/accounts_chip_group"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:singleLine="true"
                    app:singleSelection="true" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/datePickerTIL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/accounts_scroll_view"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_from_border"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_from_border"
                android:hint="@string/date"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_calendar">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/datePickerTIET"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="false" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/noteTIL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/datePickerTIL"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_from_border"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_from_border"
                android:hint="@string/note"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_pen">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_from_border"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_from_border"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/filledButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_from_border"
            android:text="@string/add_transaction"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

